# Pegar nome tabela com Trigger/Function no Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, funções, trigger, psql

Estou implementando uma forma de replicação simples de duas tabelas ou mais. Tenho a tabela **replicação** que possui o nome da tabela a ser replicada e o id.

Para alimentar a tabela **replicação** tenho uma trigger em cada tabela que será replicada pegando as informações delas e inserindo na tabela **replicação**.

Sei que na minha function posso usar o **OLD** e **NEW** para pegar os campos da tabela que disparou a trigger, porém eu queria, dentro da function (que será executada pela trigger) pegar o nome da tabela que disparou o evento.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Porque não passa como parâmetro pela function? `function_rep('tabela_origem');`

Comment: @Everson pode ser, só que na trigger como eu passaria esse parâmetro? Lembrando que quem vai chamar a função é a trigger que por sua vez é disparada por uma tabela a qual eu quero o nome.

Comment: @Everson

Eu queria algo mais genérico tipo:


`CREATE TRIGGER replica AFTER INSERT
ON teste1 FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE inserir_em_replicacao(old.nome_tabela);`


Ai eu poderia executar essa trigger no banco só alterando o nome da tabela no cabeçalho.

Answer (score 1):

Procurando na documentação do postgres encontrei como pegar, é só usar o:
**TG_TABLE_NAME**

[Documentação Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)